# Infusing different color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color-reproduction

I'm fairly new with adobe illustrator but how can you achieve this kind of affect?

Were there's a tint of yellow in some parts of the green area

I colored this by hand but I'm not sure how to replicate this in illustrator

[image: Mixing color]

If anyone can link a video tutorial that would be great as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to research **[Gradient Mesh](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html)**.

[image]